# Target Address in Apex Email Error

Tags: apex, email

I am writing a trigger that sends email upon the insertion of attachments. To make it configurable, I havea custom setting that determines the email recipients called FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c that determines the recipients.

```
List<FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c> emList = New List<FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c>();
        emList = [SELECT Email_Recipient__c FROM FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c WHERE Email_Recipient__c != Null]; 

List<String> sendToAddresses = New List<String>();        

    for (FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c FHAE : emList){
        sendToAddresses.add(FHAE.Email_Recipient__c);
    }
```

Eventually the email is sent like so:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> sendingEmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

        mailItem.setToAddresses(sendToAddresses);
        mailitem.setSubject(subject);   
        mailItem.setPlainTextBody(body);
        mailItem.setFileAttachments(attach);

    sendingEmails.add(mailItem);
Messaging.sendEmail(sendingEmails);
```

The part of the test class that covers this is:

```
Attachment testAttach = new Attachment();
        testAttach.Name = 'Test Attachment Name';
        testAttach.Body = Blob.valueOf('Test Attachment Body');
        testAttach.ParentId = testMessage.Id;
    insert testAttach;

    List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attList = New List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>();

    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment testEFA = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();   
        testEFA.body = testAttach.body;
        testEFA.setFileName(testAttach.Name);
        attList.add(testEFA);

    FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c testFHAE1 = New FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c();
        testFHAE1.Email_Recipient__c = 'MeTest@emailtest1.testtest.com';
        insert testFHAE1;

    FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c testFHAE2 = New FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c();
        testFHAE1.Email_Recipient__c = 'YouTest@emailtest2.testest.com';
        insert testFHAE2;

    List<FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c> eList = new List<FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c>();
        eList.add(testFHAE1);
        eList.add(testFHAE2);

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage testMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        List<String> toAddressesList = new List<String>();
            for(FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c f : elist){
                toAddressesList.add(f.Email_Recipient__c);
            }
        testMail.setToAddresses(toAddressesList);
        testMail.Subject = 'Test Subject';
        testMail.setPlainTextBody('Test Text Body');
        testMail.setFileAttachments(attList);

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> testMailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        testMailList.add(testMail);


    Messaging.sendEmail(testMailList);
```

Despite the fact that the test class goes through a list to set the toAddresses, it says that this line is not covered by code, and the test also fails, stating: "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing target address (target, to, cc, bcc): []" Since I have in, in fact, set the ToAddresses, and I am not using a template that requires a target object Id. The stack trace points to the line in the test class that says "insert testAttach." Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edited. Thanks, that was a good catch, but unfortunately it didn't resolve things. same error still.

Comment: your test class shouldnt be sending email - it should only insert attachments after mocking `FinanceHardwareAttachmentsEmail__c`, You can only verify that a request to send email was made, not the actual email itself (without more elaborate refactoring and unit testing)